# Changing Background image with Javascript, only display first image once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using the following code to change the background image of my html page, however I only want the first image to be shown once, and the others to remain rotating. Looking for help on what I should change/add to this code for this to happen

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var header = $('body');

    var backgrounds = new Array(
        'url(http://www.example.com/image-1.png)', 'url(http://www.example.com/image-2.png)', 'url(http://www.example.com/image-3.png)'
    );

    var current = 0;

    function nextBackground() {
        current++;
        current = current % backgrounds.length;
        header.css('background-image', backgrounds[current]);
    }
    setInterval(nextBackground, 7500);

    header.css('background-image', backgrounds[0]);
});
</script>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Add `backgrounds.shift()` after `header.css('background-image', backgrounds[0]);`

Comment: Fantastic that worked thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Change your nextBackground function to this:

```
function nextBackground() {
    current++;
    if (current === backgrounds.length)
        current = 1;
    header.css('background-image', backgrounds[current]);
}
```